# Matching string on a condition using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string for example:

```
s = 'Knorr 12x10g Fish bouillon cube'
```

I want to get 12x10g part using regex. The logic would be to find the first digit and extend it until find a first space. Right now I am just able to match only this specific string with the following regex.

```
val = re.findall(r'\s[0-9].x[0-9].g', s]
```

But I have kg, ml and other kinds of weights metrics in my data. So this regex not work with all. Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: A single example is usually a pretty bad way to describe what you want a regex to match.

Answer (score 2):

> The logic would be to find the first digit and extend it until find a first space.

You may use `\d\S*` regex:

```
import re
s = 'Knorr 12x10g Fish bouillon cube'
val = re.findall(r'\d\S*', s)
print(val)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ocnUxm)

The `re.findall` method will find all non-overlapping occurrences of substrings starting with a digit (`\d`) with 0+ characters other than whitespace after it (`\S*`). If the number of non-whitespaces should be non-zero, replace `*` with `+` (1 or more occurrences).

To avoid matching trailing punctuation, you may add `\b` at the end of the regex pattern (`r'\d\S*\b'`).

Comment: Note that this regex is rather generic, you may need to refine it to better suit your set of data.

Comment: Thanks. Just for the sake of knowing. If I want to make a regex that should a contain a particular character. For example, in this case If I want to make regex that should contain 'x' and then rest of the logic, how can I convert the same regex ?

Answer (score 1):

```
\s[0-9]{1,}.x[0-9]{1,}[a-z]{1,}\s
```

After this, you can choose to use `.strip()` to the derived string.

Answer (score 0):

For regex:

```
\d+\w\d+\w*(?=\s)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1orSGQ/1

---

For Python

```
import re
text = '''s = 'Knorr 12x10g Fish bouillon cube'
s = 'Knorr 12x10kg Fish bouillon cube'
s = 'Knorr 12x10gram Fish bouillon cube'
'''

for m in re.finditer(r"\d+\w\d+\w*(?=\s)", text):

    print('%s' % (m.group(0)))
```

Output

```
12x10g
12x10kg
12x10gram
```